# SQL Database and replicating changes to android/ios phone

Tags: android, sql

I've some knowledge on databases. I've used them for some android projects, but recently I am in the need of making a website in which someone can see the data of each table that is accessible to them. The problem is that they must be able to change this data, and this change must replicate into the android app that the  users use to upload their data.

E.g:

Users upload their ringtone, someone using this website decides that they need ANOTHER ringtone. It is changed, and now this change should appear on the other person's phone and be used as the ringtone. This must be instant because speed is crucial. Please tell me if you know of documentation or something similar to this. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is literally impossible. Well, maybe not with a quantum computer but I'm not an expert on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. Use a SQL trigger to populate an audit table.  Then a service to process the audit table and send push notifications to mobile.  Push notifications are instant.  The service can be configured to process every 10 seconds or so.  You can tweak the service interval but whatever you do, do not try and send the push notification inside the trigger.  Use the audit table.